# How to run a function during a limited time?

Tags: timer, lua, coronasdk, delayed-execution

I've a function and would like to call here each 2 seconds during 3 seconds.

I tried `timer.performwithDelay()` but it doesn't answer to my question.

Here is the function I want to call each 2 secondes during 3 seconds :

```
function FuelManage(event)  
    if lives > 0 and pressed==true then         

        lifeBar[lives].isVisible=false
        lives = lives - 1
--      print( lifeBar[lives].x )   
        livesValue.text = string.format("%d", lives)


    end
end
```

How can I use `timer.performwithDelay(2000, callback, 1)` to call my function `FuelManage(event)` ?

Comment: each 2 seconds during 3 seconds? that is one call delayed 2 seconds from the point of the call right? `timer.performwithDelay(2000, callback, 1)` will do that for you.

Comment: I'd love to help but "each 2 seconds during 3 seconds" does not make sense. The first call will be two seconds after `performWithDelay`, and next call would be another 2 seconds after that so a total of 4 seconds from very first call to performWithDelay, and that does not fall in "during 3 seconds". Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like what you are actually after is to start a few check 2 seconds from "now", for a duration of 3 seconds. You can schedule registering and unregistering for the `enterFrame` events. Using this will call your FuelManage function every time step during the period of interest:

```
    function cancelCheckFuel(event)
        Runtime:removeListener('enterFrame', FuelManager)
    end

    function FuelManage(event)  
        if lives > 0 and pressed==true then         
            lifeBar[lives].isVisible=false
            lives = lives - 1
            -- print( lifeBar[lives].x )   
            livesValue.text = string.format("%d", lives)    
        end
    end

    -- fuel management: 
    local startFuelCheckMS = 2000    -- start checking for fuel in 2 seconds
    local fuelCheckDurationMS = 3000 -- check for 3 seconds
    local stopFuelCheckMS = startFuelCheckMS + fuelCheckDurationMS
    timer.performWithDelay(
        startFuelCheckMS, 
        function() Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame', FuelManager) end, 
        1)
    timer.performWithDelay(
        stopFuelCheckMS, 
        function() Runtime:removeEventListener('enterFrame', FuelManager) end,  
        1)
```

If this is too high frequency, then you'll want to use a timer, and keep track of time:

```
    local fuelCheckDurationMS = 3000 -- check for 3 seconds
    local timeBetweenChecksMS = 200 -- check every 200 ms
    local totalCheckTimeMS = 0
    local startedChecking = false

    function FuelManage(event)  
        if lives > 0 and pressed==true then         
            lifeBar[lives].isVisible=false
            lives = lives - 1
            -- print( lifeBar[lives].x )   
            livesValue.text = string.format("%d", lives)    
        end

        if totalCheckTimeMS < 3000 then
            timer.performWithDelay(timeBetweenChecksMS, FuelManage, 1)
            if startedChecking then 
                totalCheckTimeMS = totalCheckTimeMS + timeBetweenChecksMS 
            end
            startedChecking = true
        end
    end

    -- fuel management: 
    local startFuelCheckMS = 2000    -- start checking for fuel in 2 seconds
    timer.performWithDelay(startFuelCheckMS, FuelManage, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. I inserted the code, but it says : Attempt to call field 'performwithDelay' (a nil value) (according to the timer.performwithDelay(3000, FuelManage, 1) )

Comment: @MehmetAitAddi Please show some effort when trying people's answers, only if spent a whole hour trying to figure it out, then you put such comment. Because you ought to have figured that one out on your own (if you can't then you're tackling too advanced): the problem is that I misspelled it, it should be `performWithDelay`. I've updated my answer. Also, are you trying solution 3 or 4 of my answer?

Comment: Oh my god, i'm so sorry :-( I tried the answser 4. I've add the "fuel management" in a functon called "Checkfuel" and added a listenner on it. I've edited my question.

Comment: @MehmetAitAddi Ok woa! what you have now is an entirely different question. A question should not be changed like that. For one thing, it was a good question, just unclear. Please revert to latest version of your previous question, close it (accept and hopefully you also upvote) and post a new question.

Comment: @MehmetAitAddi Thanks for restoring your question. Is there a reason that the question is not closed? The question of "2 seconds in 3 seconds" is solved or not? Bar speed is different question, so even if speed wrong, should not affect if this question closed.

Answer (score 0):

Set a timer inside a timer like this:

```
function FuelManage(event)  
    if lives > 0 and pressed==true then         
        lifeBar[lives].isVisible=false
        lives = lives - 1
--      print( lifeBar[lives].x )   
        livesValue.text = string.format("%d", lives)    
    end
end

-- Main timer, called every 2 seconds
timer.performwithDelay(2000, function()
    -- Sub-timer, called every second for 3 seconds
    timer.performwithDelay(1000, FuelManage, 3)
end, 1)
```

Be careful though because the way it's setup know you will have an infinite number of timer running very soon... Since the first timer has a lower lifetime than the second one. So you might think if you would like to secure the second timer by making sure it's cancelled first before calling it again, this kind of thing.